# What is the random number algorithm with the longest periodicity?

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I want to create a random number function but I don't want to use any already-made `rand()` function or method.

Is there a well-known algorithm or theory about it that I would call in?

Comment: "Best" by what criteria? What's wrong with a pre-existing function?

Comment: I use my portable cyclotron, entangling an electron and anti-electron, wait for annihilation and from the resulting energy signature take my random value.

Comment: I wish to creat the largest periodicity rand that I can, doenst matter the hardware resources that I would spend, pre-existing are simple and created to be fast.

Comment: Any decent algorithm will have a good pre-existing implementation, not necessarily the compiler provided `rand` function.

Comment: You should rename the question "What is the random number algorithm with the longest periodicity". I'm voting to reopen as it seems a legitimate question.

Comment: Multiply-with-carry can have huge period (depending on the constants) without needing too many bits of state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly want a `linear congruential pseudo-random number generator`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

There are a few criteria in the Wikipedia article to determine whether a given set of parameters will have the maximum period possible.

Comment: I was thinking in something like this. Thank you. I will take a deep look.

Answer (score 3):

Pick two different PRNGs with different periods, P_1 and P_2.  Output the XOR of the two generators individual outputs.  The combined generator will have a period of (P_1 * P_2) / GCD(P_1, P_2).  There are other ways of combining generators to give long periods, but that is one of the simplest.